# treesit-install-language-grammar on Windows with Clang

Tags: microsoft-windows, tree-sitter

I'm trying to use tree sitter on Windows with Emacs 29.1, but running into trouble when installing a language grammar.

When I invoke the `treesit-install-language-grammar` function with the arguments

- json
- https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-json
- master
- src
- clang
- clang++

I get the error:

> Warning (treesit): Error encountered when installing language grammar: (treesit-error Command: clang -fPIC -c -I. parser.c Error output: clang: error: unsupported option '-fPIC' for target 'i686-pc-windows-msvc'

It seems to me that it is trying to pass gcc options to clang, but I don't know where I would configure this.

How do I install tree sitter language grammars on windows for emacs with either clang or mcvc ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the code written by the maintainer of the Emacs *tree-sitter* feature for generating tree-sitter modules (< https://github.com/casouri/tree-sitter-module/blob/master/build.sh >). In it, the compiler used is `cc` instead of `gcc`, which means **the author does not consider those options to be gcc-specific**. If you have any questions, I suggest directly raising an *issue* on GitHub.

Comment: Additionally, if I remember correctly, casouri (the author, who is known as *Yuan Fu* in the Emacs devel mailing list) also uses macOS, and therefore, he may be using `clang` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t support clang. If you want to change how the treesitter grammar modules are built, modify the function `treesit--install-language-grammar-1` in `treesit.el`. You can change it to pass whatever args the compiler requires.

Comment: Is this a problem with Emacs or with Treesitter? It appears that Treesitter does support it https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/pull/1411  but I can't tell if that's actually true.

How would I determine the correct arguments to pass to clang?

Comment: Look at the code in `install-language-grammar-1` (use `C-h f` and follow the link to the source code). You can see that it calls the compiler on several files directly, building a library that can be dynamically loaded by Emacs. You could edit those arguments so that they are the arguments that would tell clang to do the same thing gcc would do. If you don’t know what those arguments would be, perhaps consulting the [clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) would help you. The second chapter is called “Command Line Options”, so I figure that’s a good place to start.

Comment: I was able to successfully compile the .dll with clang by manually editing the arguments. However, it still did not work. Only dlls compiled with gcc appear to actually load which is a bummer. I'd like to see if anybody was able to successfully compile language modules with a compiler that comes with visual studio

Comment: What caused them not to load?

Comment: I don't know. It just said that it it couldn't find the file. However, I triple-checked the path, and it appeared correct. I gave up, installed msys2, and used the out of the box build which overwrote the clang-built dll with a gcc one and it just worked.